# docker compose up Error "Ports are not available"

Tags: docker, docker-compose, yaml, dockerfile, django-q

I am trying to run my docker container with each service on different ports, but I keep receiving an error specific to port 8000 being accessed by multiple ports when I am only using port 8000 for one service.

Everything works fine when I remove the `qcluster` service, but I don't understand why when its configured for port 8001 and not 80000

Here's the error message:

```
Error response from daemon: Ports are not available: exposing port TCP 0.0.0.0:8000 -> 0.0.0.0:0: listen tcp 0.0.0.0:8000: bind: Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted.
```

and here is the `compose.yaml` file:

```
services:
  db:
    image: postgres
    volumes:
      - ./data/db:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=***********
      - SECRET_KEY=************************
      - DB_HOST=*******************
      - DB_PWD=****************
      - DB_CERT=****************
  web:
    build:
      context: app
    command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    ports:
      - '8000:8000'
    expose:
      - '8000'
    environment:
      - SECRET_KEY=**********************
      - DB_HOST=db.***********
      - DB_PWD=***************
      - DB_CERT=*************
    depends_on:
      - db
  qcluster:
    build:
      context: app
    command: python manage.py qcluster
    volumes:
      - .:/code
    ports:
      - "8000:8001"
    depends_on:
      - db
```

Comment: What does `docker ps` yields? The error message means you already have something listening on the port 8000 of your host (may it be a container or a service).

Comment: `docker ps` yeilds ` CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                    COMMAND                  CREATED         STATUS         PORTS
           NAMES
d178f1c2c009   backendserver-qcluster   "python manage.py qc…"   8 seconds ago   Up 4 seconds   8000/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8000->8001/tcp   backendserver-qcluster-1
5eb0932e4680   postgres                 "docker-entrypoint.s…"   2 minutes ago   Up 5 seconds   5432/tcp
           backendserver-db-1 `

Answer (score 2):

Seems that you have another container/service listening on port 8000.

Run `docker container ls` and check if there are containers already listening on 8000. If so, just kill that container and try again.

If there are no running container, maybe there's another service that is listening on that port. To identify it, run

```
lsof -i TCP:8000 | grep LISTEN
```

to obtain its PID (a number that represent the ID of that process). Then, kill it using

```
kill -9 YOUR_PID_HERE
```

Comment: I have some `TCP *:eforward` thing running that keeps spinning up even after I kill the process on port. What can be done here?